# Cannot post non-app url to feed

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

When I publish a post using the graph api (php), and then click the link on the post, I get the following error:

> API Error Code: 191 API Error Description: The specified URL is not
>   owned by the application Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by
>   the application.

The link url is not the same as the one specified as the Site URL or Canvas URL, but this has worked for over a year now and just stopped working in the past few days.

See any of the recent links on http://www.facebook.com/becki.yore. These all worked until a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Check your app settings for the migration „Stream post URL security” – is that enabled by any chance?